# How to insert a long string value in a column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO [Bitflow].[dbo].[GlobalConfiguration]
           ([Key]
           ,[Value]
           ,[Description]
           ,[DATE_LAST_UPDATED]
           ,[DATE_CREATED])
     VALUES
           ('OPERATIONS_BES_USERS_SQL_QUERY_01'
           ,'select DisplayName,EmailAddress,RelayServer, ModelName, PhoneNumber, PIN, 

HomeNetwork, ActiveCarrier, ICCID, 
             convert(varchar(10),CreationDate, 101)CreationDate,convert(varchar(10),ActivationDate, 

101)ActivationDate, 
             MsgsForwarded, MsgsSent,convert(varchar(10),LastFwdDate, 101)LastFwdDate,convert

(varchar(10),LastSentDate, 101)LastSentDate, 
             CurrentPolicyName, ServiceName from TEMP_BESselect 

DisplayName,EmailAddress,RelayServer, ModelName, PhoneNumber, PIN, HomeNetwork, 

ActiveCarrier, ICCID, 
             convert(varchar(10),CreationDate, 101)CreationDate,convert(varchar(10),ActivationDate, 

101)ActivationDate, 
             MsgsForwarded, MsgsSent,convert(varchar(10),LastFwdDate, 101)LastFwdDate,convert

(varchar(10),LastSentDate, 101)LastSentDate, 
             CurrentPolicyName, ServiceName from TEMP_BES'
           ,'Query for respective Bes Server'
           ,CAST(0x0000A2A600000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A2A600000000 AS DateTime))
GO
```

The 2nd value is a huge string storing it via `nvarchar(max)` lot of whitespaces are there while retrieving from c# code want to remove that. And what is compatible datatype to retrieve the value for `nvarchar(max)` in C#? I want to retrieve this value

Comment: In c# you can use System.String as a compatible datatype

Comment: add the values as parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use common [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and for your second parameter you can do the following

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@Value"].Value = longString;
```

where `longString` is your query parameter

Comment: I guess you didn't my question the data type of Value is Nvarchar(max) varchar can't store it and I want to remove the white spaces from the value

Comment: Why do you want remove the spaces? If you want it try just with `string.Replace`

Comment: Is there any way while inserting the value itself in sqlserver when   the string exceeds a line spaces are inserted there only can I avoid that?

Comment: if you want to remove newLine characters from the string try `longString.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're generating the above query through a C# app. Use the below to eliminate multiple whitespaces:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
string input = "This is   text with   far  too   much     whitespace.";
string pattern = "\\s+";
string replacement = " ";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Comment: No I am directly inserting in sqlserver not using c#